# Php opens as Text when usign "send"

Tags: php, html, text, phpmyadmin, localhost

So, i've be reading a lot of post here, but as my english is not that good, i cant understand all of it.

Sorry if this has been asked here before AND ANSWERED.

My problem is that, when i launch my html file wich contains a form it opens fine... but when i click the "send" buton, it opens the post.php file as a text and doesnt launch it.

I've managed since reading your posts, that it could be a link problem and it was. If i open it from the html file, the php opens at "file:///C:/wamp64/www/Pagina/Insertar.php" (and it fails) but if i type "Localhost/Pagina/Insertar.php" it opens just fine and upload the //empty// data to my database.

What can i do to make the "send" button work? i mean, make it goes to localhost instead of file://c.

Thank you in anticipate.

( and "insertar.php" is in the same folder)

Comment: That might have something to do with the mime-type of the page that is received by your browser. Since it seems that you are not hosting your site on a proper web server, but instead are just opening file:/// URIs in your browser, things are bound to go wrong.

Comment: PHP is only executed when it's accessed through a server, using a `file:` URL won't execute it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP scripts are only executed when loaded through a server. It sounds like you're using a relative URL for the `action` attribute, and loading the HTML page from a local file instead of the server. So you need to change the `action` to point to the server.

```
<form action="http://localhost/Pagina/insertar.php">
```

Comment: Man you are awesome! i'm working with WAMP but that worked just in an awesome way! Loving you right now!!! so much thanks